# Memcached touch fails on AWS Elasticache

Tags: memcached, telnet, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to use the Memcached "touch" command to reset expiration times, but I'm consistently getting a generic error response. I've simplified things to using telnet, and I've got a pretty simple use case that demonstrates the issue.

```
set TestKey 0 60 9
TestValue
STORED
get TestKey
VALUE TestKey 0 9
TestValue
END
touch TestKey 300
ERROR
get TestKey
VALUE TestKey 0 9
TestValue
END
```

In the above snippet, I believe I am caching a value "TestValue" with the key "TestKey", and a timeout of 60 seconds. I'm then reading the value (using the key), which demonstrates it is stored correctly. I try to use `touch` to set the expiration to 300 seconds, but I get a response: `ERROR`. Finally, I get the value again (mostly to demonstrate that the entire test happened before the original value times out).

Additional details:
I also get `ERROR` if I try to touch a key that doesn't exist, or use the `gat` or gats` commands (to Get And Touch)

I've tried to make sure all my commands are formatted according to https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt

Am I using these commands incorrectly? Does AWS ElastiCache for Memcached lack support for touch? (I can't find any documentation asserting that it does or does not)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - We were running version 1.4.5 of the memcached engine, but apparently touch isn't fully supported (at least outside binary mode) until 1.4.24.

Upgrading to the latest engine version (1.6.12) resolved the issue.